# 'Undefined control sequence' with \addplot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

When trying to insert a TikZ figure, using `\addplot`, I've got an 'undefined control sequence'. My code is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
\addplot[only marks] file[x index=0, y index=1]{baba.txt};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

where `baba.txt` is just the simple table:

```
0 1
1 0
1 1
0 0
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: what is the exact error after that message ?

Comment: Are you missing axis environment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
  \begin{axis}
\addplot+[only marks] file[x index=0, y index=1]{baba.txt};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you add what the problem is and why your code fixes it? I have the same error but (obviously) other code. But without any context or explanation, I cannot adapt your solution to my problem.

Comment: For others: My problem was caused by an invalid option in `\nextgroupplot`. Since the plus version (`\addplot+`) uses default styles and appends the styles from the square brackets, I assume that this was also the cause here: Missing (=invalid) option(s)